# how to show null row(when select from database) on table in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

when I select from database and that table is null cause I'm not inserting data into database and I have to show table on my webpage(php) like space in table

PIC 1 >
[image: query is null]

PIC 2 >
[image: I wanna show space on table like this]

Answer (score 0):

make it nullable in your table

[image: null]